# C# - understanding async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The C# documentation on asynchronous programming states that:

- For CPU-bound code, you await an operation which is started on a background thread with the `Task.Run` method.
- The `await` keyword is where the magic happens. It yields control to the caller of the method that performed `await`, and it ultimately allows a UI to be responsive or a service to be elastic.
- When the `await` keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete.

With that in mind, I tested some CPU bound code *(finding a Bitcoin block hash seemed suitably modern and difficult)* to try and understand exactly what is happening when async/await is applied:

**Example**

```
namespace AsyncronousSample
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result = await HashAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 4);

            Console.WriteLine("Calculating hash...");
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static async Task<string> HashAsync(byte[] data, int difficulty = 1)
        {
            int nonce = default;
            string result = default;

            byte[] GetDataBytesWithNOnce()
            {
                return data
                    .Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(nonce++))
                    .ToArray();
            }

            byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] bytes)
            {
                using (SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create())
                {
                    return sha.ComputeHash(sha.ComputeHash(bytes));
                }
            }

            string ConvertToHash(byte[] hashBytes)
            {
                return BitConverter
                    .ToString(hashBytes)
                    .Replace("-", string.Empty)
                    .ToLower();
            }

            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                do
                {
                    result = ConvertToHash(ComputeHash(GetDataBytesWithNOnce()));
                } while (!result.StartsWith(new string('0', difficulty)));

                return result;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, for the more astute of you, who are interested in Bitcoin and how it works, this isn't the *real* Bitcoin hash algorithm, but it is `SHA256(SHA256(data + nonce))`, so it's difficult enough for the example.

**Expectation versus Reality**

I expected that `Calculating hash...` would be printed immediately to the console, and the result would then print when the hash had finally been found.

In reality, nothing is printed to the console until the hash is found.

**Question**

Where have I gone wrong in my understanding, or my code?

Comment: That's because you `await` before printing.

Comment: well, you await it..

Comment: @SLaks "When the await keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete." - In my mind this means that the awaited method is suspended and the Main method gets back control until the awaited methods completes, and finally, `Console.WriteLine(result)` resolves and completes? - I know, I'm probably completely off the mark

Comment: it suspends the calling method (the method with `async`) and yields control back to the caller of async method (whatever called the method)

Comment: Imagine that await splits method into two parts, before and after. If you are familiar with javascript, imagine some ajax query which always has 'then(...)' contination. Part after await is such 'then' continuation, but written sequentially, without "callback hell".

Comment: @series0ne: Yes, `Main()` gets back control.  But then `Main()` also `await`s, so it gives up control again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're calling `await` on `HashAsync` the control will be yielded to the caller, which is this case is .NET Framework itself, which called your `Main` method.

I think the easiest way to see how this works would be to assign the `Task` returned from `HashAsync` to a variable but not `await` it until after the `Console.WriteLine`:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<string> resultTask = HashAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 4);

    Console.WriteLine("Calculating hash...");'

    string result = await resultTask;

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.Read();
}
```

With this change, once you call into `HashAsync` it will push work to the background using `Task.Run` and return you a `Task` to observe progress of that work. But because you're not `await`ing it `Main` method will continue executing and `Calculating hash...` will be printed. Only once you call `await resultTask` control will be returned to whoever called `Main` and execution will be suspended.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you `await` it.

I think the best way to understand it is just to imagine code that is `async` as a block of code that runs concurrently, but once you await it you say: "I need the value now and will not proceed further unless I get it", if you don't await, then you're working with a task which could be potentially in an incomplete state.

Comment: If that's the case, how is this different from non async/await code...I feel like I've missed something.

Comment: @series0ne Try it on a UI thread, one will block (hang) the UI, the other will yield back to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `string result = await HashAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 4);`

you are suspending the caller method (in your case your Main) and it will continue, as soon as the "awaited" call is done.

The printing to the console, is done in the same caller method, so as soon as `HashAsync` is completed, you will see the "Calculating hash...".

Answer (score 0):

When the executing thread or the UI thread executes a line of code that starts with await, the UI thread is automatically unblocked and waits for the operation to complete while user can interact with the UI, after some time when async operation is completed then code will start its execution right were it left it in the first place.

Update

In c# 7.1  main method can also be async and the async await can be used in this way

```
  class Program
  {
      public static async Task Main(string[] args)
      {
         await Task.Run(async () =>
         {
            MyAsyncFunc();
         });
         Console.WriteLine("done");
         Console.ReadLine();
      }

    static async Task MyAsyncFunc()
     {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
     }
  }
```

Comment: What about in a console application?

Comment: In Console application the Main method cannot be async so your have to run a task and manually make it Wait.

Comment: But, my `Main` method IS async (as per it's introduction in C# 7.1)

Comment: Well C# 7.1 does support the async in Main method , to achieve your  target you can do it like
 await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                HashAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 4);
            });
it will produce the desired result.

Comment: i have tested it myself, the console will print the calculating hash first